# Random 504 errors on POST api.soundcloud.com/tracks

Tags: soundcloud

Starting from yesterday, 29th Jan 2018, at about 12:33 UTC we've seen an increasing rate of 504 errors when POST /tracks

The 504 comes from CloudFront that is apparently unable to connect to the origin, according the (HTML) error message we get:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-\/\/W3C\/\/DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional\/\/EN\" \"http:\/\/www.w3.org\/TR\/html4\/loose.dtd\">\n<HTML><HEAD><META HTTP-EQUIV=\"Content-Type\" CONTENT=\"text\/html; charset=iso-8859-1\">\n<TITLE>ERROR: The request could not be satisfied<\/TITLE>\n<\/HEAD><BODY>\n<H1>ERROR<\/H1>\n<H2>The request could not be satisfied.<\/H2>\n<HR noshade size=\"1px\">\nCloudFront attempted to establish a connection with the origin, but either the attempt failed or the origin closed the connection.\n<BR clear=\"all\">\n<HR noshade size=\"1px\">\n<PRE>\nGenerated by cloudfront (CloudFront)\nRequest ID: QCLJ3C5CUq53tf0-uoxn8wU69FKXmUdf9tym0lUHrk8tLfVZZxiKHw==\n<\/PRE>\n<ADDRESS>\n<\/ADDRESS>\n<\/BODY><\/HTML>
```

The issue is random. If we retry the request from the same IP or a different one, sometimes fails again, sometimes succeed. It looks like the issue is related to a restricted set of backends.

Are you aware of any issue?